# Unable to concat typescript modules (.ts) files into single output(.js) using --out Comment: Getting Error

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript1.5

I am new to Typescript. I've been trying to concatenate typescript modules by using the `tsc --out` command. But I'm getting some error. There is no information about the error. Below is the process, I've tired.

.ts files I have:

Validation.ts:

```
module Validation {  
    export interface StringValidator {
       isAcceptable(s: string): boolean;
    }
}
```

ZipCodeValidator.ts:

```
/// <reference path="Validation.ts" />
module Validation {
    var numberRegexp = /^[0‐9]+$/;
    export class ZipCodeValidator implements StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string) {
            return s.length === 5 && numberRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }
}
```

LettersOnlyValidator.ts:

```
/// <reference path="Validation.ts" />
module Validation {
    var lettersRegexp = /^[A‐Za‐z]+$/;
    export class LettersOnlyValidator implements StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string) {
            return lettersRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Test.ts:

```
/// <reference path="Validation.ts" />
/// <reference path="LettersOnlyValidator.ts" />
/// <reference path="ZipCodeValidator.ts" />
// Some samples to try
var strings = ['Hello', '98052', '101'];
// Validators to use
var validators: { [s: string]: Validation.StringValidator; } = {};
validators['ZIP code'] = new Validation.ZipCodeValidator();
validators['Letters only'] = new Validation.LettersOnlyValidator();
// Show whether each string passed each validator
strings.forEach(s => {
    for (var name in validators) {
        console.log('"' + s + '" ' + (validators[name].isAcceptable(s) ? ' matches ' : ' does not match ') + name);
    }
});
```

tsc command:

```
tsc --out sample.js Test.ts
```

Error:

```
error TS6053: File 'ΓÇÉout.ts' not found.  
error TS6054: File 'sample.js' must have extension '.ts' or '.d.ts'
```

Please let me know the way to resolve. And one more, is there any way to concat the typescript module in gulp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using wrong dash character in your `tsc --out`.
TypeScript compiler looks at your command and instead of ***"invoke tsc with file `Test.ts` and output to `sample.js`"*** sees something along the lines of ***"invoke tsc with 3 files: `--out`, `sample.js`, `Test.ts`"***. It then looks for these files and tries to compile them.

To fix the problem, just copy&paste the command with the correct dash character:
`tsc --out sample.js Test.ts`

Answer (score 2):

I won't answer you exactly because i don't use the `tsc` command.

But if I were you, I would make it automatic (with Gulp for example) :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var addsrc = require('gulp-add-src');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('tsc', function () {
    return gulp.src(['*.ts']) // all your ts files here (check the path)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(typescript({
            sortOutput: true
        })) 
        .js // compile with tsc, ordered with _reference.ts
        .pipe(addsrc('external.js')) // add an external javascript file (if needed)
        .pipe(concat('app.js')) // concat all in one file
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write()) // generate the .map
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist')); // write all in the dist folder
});
```

**In short :**

- [`gulp-typescript`](https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript) : **tsc** for gulp
- [`gulp-sourcemaps`](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps) : allows you to generate the **.map** (to link between the .ts files and the .js files)
- [`gulp-add-src`](https://github.com/urish/gulp-add-src) : allows you to **add sources files in the pipe**. It's usefull to push some javascript files in the process.
- [`gulp-concat`](https://github.com/wearefractal/gulp-concat) : **concat** all the files

Comment: No idea why this wasn't accepted it definitely works and is a better approach to automate the build process.  Thank you I was hunting high and low to get an understanding on how to get my js built as one file but the sourcemaps to Typescript intact!