# How can I concatenate typescript output without breaking node imports?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm concatenating the output of the typescript compiler by using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30665921/469777).  Doing so however then breaks imports I have to relative path modules in node.

The following successfully compiles & concatenates;

```js
// Group.ts
class Group { 
    doSomething() { ... }
}
export = Group

// Main.ts
import Group = require('./Group');
new Group().doSomething();
```

But executing it then throws;

```
Error: Cannot find module './Group'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\git\nzb-watch\src\compiled.js:64:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:429:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:999:3
```

How can I achieve concatenation of the compiled js without throwing this error?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than asking the TypeScript compiler to shove everything into a single file you should use a module bundler that will take care of creating the bundle and then loading modules from the bundle at runtime. There are a multitude of bundlers out there, including [rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup), [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/), [browserify](http://browserify.org/), and many more.

Answer (score 0):

import ... require is for js files. Once you move over to ts, you use `import ... from`

```
import Group from './Group';
```

Comment: switching to that (and I also had to switch `export = Group` for `export default Group`) results in the same error: `Cannot find module './Group'`

Comment: I feared so, I think you also need embrace webpack or systemjs instead of simple concatenation